# Использование контекста в template in Class Base View Django

Tags: django

Не совсем понимаю как передать контекст в Success template.Т.е. пользователь вводит данные в форму и нужно эти данные отобразить в template. 
Пробовал разные варианты:`get_queryset`, `get_context`, `get_context_data`.
Также не ясно как сохранять данные в сессию.
View

```
class LoginFormView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = "blog/login.html"
    success_url = "/blog"

    def form_valid(self, form):        
        self.user = form.get_user()
        login(self.request, self.user)
        return super(LoginFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Также не ясно как сохранять данные в сессию. View

self.request.session['data'] = 123
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#examples

> Не совсем понимаю как передать контекст в Success template.

когда данные формы отправлял через ajax, то я делал так

```
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 def form_valid(request):
     ...
     return JsonResponse({'success': True, 'redirect_url': self.get_success_url()})
```